# Unable to use JSON.parse() on array encoded with PHP's json_encode()

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, encode

I have a Vue component that gets data from Apache Solr, and the data from the field that I'm dealing with is an array that was created using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP. Here's my method in my component:

```
    data () {
      return {
        slideshow: {},
        slides: {}
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.getSlideshow()
    },
    methods: {
    getSlideshow: function () {
      var language = this.language
      // Get slideshow record from Solr.
      const params = new URLSearchParams()
      params.append('fq', 'bundle:slideshow')
      params.append('fq', 'entity_id:' + this.slideshowNid)
      params.append('fq', 'ss_language:' + language)
      params.append('fq', 'entity_type:node')
      params.append('wt', 'json')
      params.append('rows', 1)
      axios.get('https://mysolrurl.com/solr/myindex/select', {
        params: params
      })
      .then(response => {
        var slideshow = response.data.response.docs[0]
        this.slides = slideshow.sm_field_product_image_desktop
      })
    }
  }
```

and ideally what I'd like to be able to do in my template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="slide in slides">
        <img v-bind:src="slide.url" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem I'm having is parsing the array that is returned from my `sm_field_product_image_desktop` field. This is the structure that I get:

```
Array [
  0: "{\"id\":\"6258\",\"url\":\"\\/\\/dam-assets.mysite.com\\/s3fs-public\\/F-279fc_03b_1500x1000_0.png\",\"caption\":\"\",\"alt\":\"My-Product\",\"thumbnail\":\"\"}",
  1: "{\"id\":\"3619\",\"url\":\"\\/\\/dam-assets.mysite.com\\/s3fs-public\\/F-279fc_14b_1500x1000.png\",\"caption\":\"\",\"alt\":\"My Product\",\"thumbnail\":\"\"}",
  2:"{\"id\":\"3616\",\"url\":\"\\/\\/dam-assets.mysite.com\\/s3fs-public\\/Fluke%20279%20FC%20kit_300dpi_542x357mm_C_NR-20892.jpg\",\"caption\":\"\",\"alt\":\"My Product\",\"thumbnail\":\"\"}",
  3:"{\"id\":\"36177\",\"url\":\"\\/\\/dam-assets.mysite.com\\/s3fs-public\\/Fluke%20279%20FC%20power%20panel_300dpi_352x234mm_C_NR-20990.jpg\",\"caption\":\"\",\"alt\":\"My Product\",\"thumbnail\":\"\"}"
]
```

If I try to use `JSON.parse()` on the array, I get an error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 146

If I iterate over the array and individually parse each item, then I can parse it and get an individual object that I can read.

```
var slides = slideshow.sm_field_product_image_desktop
slides.forEach(function (item) {
  var parsedItem = (JSON.parse(item))
  console.log('URL: ' + parsedItem.url)
})
```

But that means that if I want to be able to actually access the URL in my template, I have to create a new object by looping through the one returned from Solr and individually adding each one. Is that correct, or is there a quicker (or different) way to get the array returned from Solr parsed so I can iterate over it in my template?

UPDATE: For Sebastian, here is the log output of `slides`:

```
{"id":"6258","url":"\/\/dam-assets.fluke.com\/s3fs-public\/F-279fc_03b_1500x1000_0.png","caption":"","alt":"Fluke 279 FC True-RMS","thumbnail":""},{"id":"3619","url":"\/\/dam-assets.fluke.com\/s3fs-public\/F-279fc_14b_1500x1000.png","caption":"","alt":"Fluke 279 FC True-RMS","thumbnail":""},{"id":"3616","url":"\/\/dam-assets.fluke.com\/s3fs-public\/Fluke%20279%20FC%20kit_300dpi_542x357mm_C_NR-20892.jpg","caption":"","alt":"Fluke 279 FC True-RMS","thumbnail":""},{"id":"36177","url":"\/\/dam-assets.fluke.com\/s3fs-public\/Fluke%20279%20FC%20power%20panel_300dpi_352x234mm_C_NR-20990.jpg","caption":"","alt":"Fluke 279 FC True-RMS","thumbnail":""}
```

UPDATE2: For FDavidov, here is how the field is represented in Solr itself:

```
"sm_field_product_image_desktop": [
          "{\"id\":\"6258\",\"url\":\"\\/\\/dam-assets.fluke.com\\/s3fs-public\\/F-279fc_03b_1500x1000_0.png\",\"caption\":\"\",\"alt\":\"Fluke 279 FC True-RMS\",\"thumbnail\":\"\"}",
          "{\"id\":\"3619\",\"url\":\"\\/\\/dam-assets.fluke.com\\/s3fs-public\\/F-279fc_14b_1500x1000.png\",\"caption\":\"\",\"alt\":\"Fluke 279 FC True-RMS\",\"thumbnail\":\"\"}",
          "{\"id\":\"3616\",\"url\":\"\\/\\/dam-assets.fluke.com\\/s3fs-public\\/Fluke%20279%20FC%20kit_300dpi_542x357mm_C_NR-20892.jpg\",\"caption\":\"\",\"alt\":\"Fluke 279 FC True-RMS\",\"thumbnail\":\"\"}",
          "{\"id\":\"36177\",\"url\":\"\\/\\/dam-assets.fluke.com\\/s3fs-public\\/Fluke%20279%20FC%20power%20panel_300dpi_352x234mm_C_NR-20990.jpg\",\"caption\":\"\",\"alt\":\"Fluke 279 FC True-RMS\",\"thumbnail\":\"\"}"
```

Comment: Why isn't `getSlideshow` into the `methods` property?

Comment: I think, your php function doesnt return correct type.. is it return with print?

Comment: @whoan, it is, I just didn't paste the entire script into the question. I've updated it.

Comment: What you are showing as an array is NOT an array. It would be if you remove the first part of each entry (i.e. `0:`, `1:`, etc.).

Comment: @FDavidov I updated the question with the output from Solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to parse each object and use it in your template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="slide in slides">
        <img :src="parse(slide).url" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

and add the function into the `methods` property in you javascript:

```
methods: {
    ...,
    parse (json) {
        return JSON.parse(json)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if slides as an array than, declare as an array

```
return {
  slideshow: {},
  slides: []
}
```

and use like,

```
axios.get('https://mysolrurl.com/solr/myindex/select', {
    params: params
})
.then(response => {
   var slideshow = response.data.response.docs[0]
   for (let [inx, item] of slideshow.sm_field_product_image_desktop.entries()) {
      slideshow.sm_field_product_image_desktop[inx] = JSON.parse(item)
   }
   this.slides = slideshow.sm_field_product_image_desktop
 })
```

Comment: I did try that, but when I do I get the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 146` error

Comment: i edited the answer, try this one. its gives you parse array in slides

Comment: Here you can see the outout: https://jsfiddle.net/nikita747/eywraw8t/56713/

Comment: Thanks, @Nik.Developer. Both answers do what  I need.